# Django: Replacing piece of url with integer variable

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to replace a url call with a variable as follows:

```
href="{% url 'educators:pay_patient' 9 %}".replace(/9/, x)
```

And the value x is just a primary key of a model, i.e. x=1,2,3, etc..

My issue is that it seems that the number of digits of x and the number it is replacing has to match. For example, x=1 works with 9 but not 90.

if x=1,

```
href="{% url 'educators:pay_patient' 90 %}".replace(/90/, x)
```

yields a 404 error with

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/educators/study/pay/90/
```

How do I make this scheme generalizable for any number of digits of x?

---

edit: As requested, my url pattern matching this view is:

```
path('educators/', include(([
    path('study/pay/<int:pk>/', educators.PayPatientView.as_view(), name='pay_patient')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback function of `replace` to assign value according to length of match.

```js
let href="{% url 'educators:pay_patient' 9010325%}"

let op = href.replace(/\d+/, function(match){
  return new Array(match.length).fill(0).map((e,i)=>i+1).join('')
})

console.log(op)
```

This is just an example added based on input you provide, you can replace regex as per you need. or you can specify more details about you url pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Code Maniac. This looks promising! I am just trying to comprehend it. It looks like match would be x in my case? And what is the console.log(op) for?

Comment: @Ambrose yeah match will be `x` in your case or whatever you want to name.  console.log(op) was just to show output :p

Answer (score 0):

from django-url official doc [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) we can assign variable as  url args and for your case  this can be

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('/educators/study/pay/<int:pk>/', your_view, name=your_view_name),
    ...
]
```

and in views.py you can have extra pk variable as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shakil. I asked this question with x as a simple variable for simplicity, but this replacement must be in this form because x is actually a custom filter tag {{ participant|get_patient_answer:occ_pk }}

Comment: i am really sorry @Ambrose, may be i am not getting your problem properly. From you updated `url` part i can see you have properly added this. If i am not wrong arg [pk] should hold any integer type of variable. There should not any problem. In this case, do this `90` is a primary key or any other variable.